# What's the use of Clflags.parse_arguments?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml

I know the module Clflags is used in the compiler source code. But the use of this module's function even have not a little explanation in the document:

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Clflags.html

In /driver/main.ml in compiler source code:

```
File: d:\src\ocaml-4.07.0\driver\main.ml
138:     Clflags.parse_arguments anonymous usage;
```

uses the function `parse_arguments`, and I know it may call /driver/compenv.ml:

```
File: d:\src\ocaml-4.07.0\driver\compenv.ml
624: let anonymous filename = defer (action_of_file filename)
```

and this will add a new item in the list of deferred_actions,

but I don't know the details of this function: parse_arguments, and the source code of clflags is not in the compiler's source code.

So how to know what the Clflags.parse_arguments really do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see sources for Clflags:

```
$ find . -name 'clflags.*'
./utils/clflags.mli
./utils/clflags.ml
```

(Maybe you typed cflags when you meant to type clflags. This is what I just did the first time.)